# prevent function from running twice

Tags: javascript, function

I have a slideshow which runs automatically and you can skip to an image by clicking on a button.

It works fine if you click one of the buttons when the image is static, but if you click while the fade functions are running it will run the functions twice which creates some kind of loop which eventually grinds the browser to a stand still!

I know I need to add some kind of "isRunning" flag, but I don't know where.

Here's a link to a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/N6F55/8/

And code also below...

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var images=new Array();
var locationToRevealCount=6;
var nextimage=2;
var t;
var doubleclick;

addIcons();

function addIcons() {
    while (locationToRevealCount>0) {
        $("#extraImageButtons").append('<img class="galleryButtons" src="http://www.steveszone.co.uk/images/button_sets/pink_square_button1n.png" alt="'+locationToRevealCount+'" />');
        images[locationToRevealCount]='http://www.tombrennand.net/'+locationToRevealCount+'a.jpg';
        locationToRevealCount--;
    };
    $('.homeLeadContent').prepend('<img class="backgroundImage" src="http://www.tombrennand.net/1a.jpg" />');
    $("#extraImageButtons img.galleryButtons[alt*='1']").attr("src","http://www.steveszone.co.uk/images/button_sets/black_square_button1n.png");
    runSlides();
}

function runSlides() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(doSlideshow,3000);
}

function doSlideshow() {
    if($('.backgroundImage').length!=0)
        $('.backgroundImage').fadeOut(500,function() {
            $('.backgroundImage').remove();
            slideshowFadeIn();
        });
    else
        slideshowFadeIn();
}

function slideshowFadeIn() {
    if(nextimage>=images.length) 
        nextimage=1;

    $("#extraImageButtons img.galleryButtons").attr("src","http://www.steveszone.co.uk/images/button_sets/pink_square_button1n.png");
    $("#extraImageButtons img.galleryButtons[alt*='"+nextimage+"']").attr("src","http://www.steveszone.co.uk/images/button_sets/black_square_button1n.png");

    $('.homeLeadContent').prepend($('<img class="backgroundImage" src="'+images[nextimage]+'" style="display:none;">').fadeIn(500,function() {
        nextimage++;
        runSlides();

    }));
}

$("#extraImageButtons img.galleryButtons").live('click', function() {
    nextimage=$(this).attr("alt");
    $("#extraImageButtons img.galleryButtons").attr("src","http://www.steveszone.co.uk/images/button_sets/pink_square_button1n.png");
    $(this).attr("src","http://www.steveszone.co.uk/images/button_sets/black_square_button1n.png");
    clearTimeout(t);
    doSlideshow();
});
});
```

html:

```
<div class="homeLeadContent" style="width:965px;">

</div>
<div id="extraImageButtons"></div>
```

Comment: What is it that you want the thing to look like?  Your code is always prepending more images into the container; is that what you want?

Comment: look at the jsfiddle... that's exactly what I want it to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes make it work better for me:

1. Down in the "extra image buttons" handler, you call "clearInterval()" but that should be changed to "clearTimeout()".
2. I added another call to "clearTimeout(t)" in the "runSlides()" function right before it sets up another timeout.

Clicking on the big "CLICK ME" button might still do weird things.

*edit* — well [here is my fork of the original jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXSLU/) and I *think* it's doing the right thing. In addition to calling "clearTimeout()" properly, I also changed the code in "doSlideshow()" so that it empties out the content `<div>` before adding another image.

Comment: These changes didn't make any difference - unless I got them wrong. The click me won't actually be there in reality, I've just not added the code to remove it when it's clicked on.

Comment: Well calling "clearInterval()" on a return value from "clearTimeout()" is wrong.  I'll update the fiddle again and fork it.

Comment: @Tom I've updated my answer with a link to a fiddle that works somewhat better.

Comment: I like it! I've found one bug in it though which may well be simple to fix. If you double click one of the icons it takes you to that image then skips a place when the slideshow continues. If you treble click it skips 2...

Comment: @Tom well it's probably because of the incrementing/decrementing that's going on. It's kind-of confusing; it might be worth taking a deep breath and structuring the code over from scratch, as there's really not that much going on.

Comment: I've tidied the code as much as I can, I still have the double/treble click problem though. Any ideas??